# PHP Pass PHP Data into JS Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file which is querying a MySQL database in order to return results, I'm currently saving the relevant result row into a PHP array and I'm then trying to echo out a JS array with the PHP data stored. I do not seem to be able to access the JS variable from my JS files.

PHP:

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $dataArray = array($row['stepNumber']);
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'var dataArray = ' . json_encode($dataArray) . ';';
    echo '</script>';
  }
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'queries/dateRangeSelect.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate},
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        window.alert(dataArray);
    },
```

`dataArray` is being reported as not defined when the `window.alert` tries to trigger.

EDIT:

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $dataArray = array($row['stepNumber']);
  }
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo $dataArray;
```

It is no longer printing errors but the console is now not printing anything.

Comment: Ok, of course this is not the way and also this way `dataArray` gets overwritten with new JSON in every loop step.

Answer (score 3):

Don't return a `<script>` tag, you can just return the JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

You probably want to do this AFTER your loop is complete and you have built up the array you wish to return.

> UPDATE

Based on your edit, I suggest something more like this:

```
$dataArray= [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $dataArray[] = array($row['stepNumber']);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dataArray);
```

Comment: Do you mean the following code:         `$dataArray = array($row['stepNumber']);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $dataArray;`

Comment: Why don't you just encode a `fetch_all` statement instead?

Comment: yes, but why is it in a loop? You cant header after echoing, so it'll break on the second iteration. You need to do it after the loop is complete and you've built your return array up the way you want

Comment: This way also change `dataType: 'json'` in the Ajax request.

Comment: I've updated the Ajax request and now the console is not printing anything.

Comment: updated, you didn't encode the array before echoing, and your loop kept overwriting your var

Comment: My current code now matches your answer update but the console is still not printing any data.

Comment: It prints data when the AJAX data type is changed back to `text`, as this is a POST request in the AJAX is the data type determined by what is being sent?